# How to close all tabs in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> we can close opened tab. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> we can select which files we want to close. Is there any other short cut to close all tabs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the short cut to close all tabs in eclipse. [Check here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html)